# Get any grid`d id and refresh that particular grid

Tags: extjs

How can I get any grid's[grid panel] id???

I'm new to Ext JS

```
`Ext.getCmp('id')`,
```

This doesn`t work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code of the grid please. And maybe a read of how to use the code tags on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

try this

for ExtJS 3

```
Ext.select("div.x-grid-panel").elements[0].id
Ext.getCmp(Ext.select("div.x-grid-panel").elements[0].id
```

for ExtJS 4

```
Ext.select('.x-grid').elements[0].id
```

refer [Ext-method-select](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-select)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of any component by just accessing the `.id` property:

```
var comp = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    html: 'Hello world!',
    id: 'foo',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

console.log(comp.id); // prints: foo
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,but it won`t be 'comp' everywhere,I need code tat should be generic,like->Ext.getCmp('dash_grid').getStore().reload();---see here i`m mentioning dash_grid has grid`s id..I don`t want to mention like this,i don`t want it to be hard coded..plz help

Comment: Why do you ask "How can I get the id" if you don't want to use the id. Make up your mind...

Comment: Rene,I clearly have specified that i`m making my code as generic...your code doesn`t match my criteria.And i`m really happy for MMT`s code..Now they`ve blocked me from asking questions.I`m sorry if i`m not yet clear...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I really don't see why you should be blocked from asking questions.